# is there any tools available to design 3D,2D objects and get the vertices and indices details for OPENGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es

i'm looking for the tool that would produce the result for OPENGL ES in terms of vertices and indices, if we draw the 2D or 3D objects. is there any tool available to create the 3D objects and produces vertices to create 3D objects for android.

i want to map these objects into android Augmented Reality. how can we map these OpenGL ES objects to AR.

Thank you....

Comment: OpenGL ES does not have "objects". It does not have a file format. It does not have a mesh format. It isn't a rendering engine; it's just a rendering library. Your job is to provide mesh data in whatever format you choose. You present this data to OpenGL ES, storing the vertex data in buffers. Then you use said vertex data to render. Also, mapping to augmented reality requires *writing an augmented reality application*, which is rather broad scope for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: thank you... is there any software tool available to generate the vertices in 3D to render in andoid..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to discourage you, but it is not as simple as you are thinking. And certainly not hard, just a few things that you need to do.

There are many tools that let you create graphic objects. Examples include [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) and [Maya](http://usa.autodesk.com/maya/)

These are not the only tools, but the thing is that objects represented in these tools are not exactly what you can use in your project, since these might (and indeed these ***do***) use other ways of representing objects than what OpelGLES does.

What you want to do is to *export* your objects, created using some 3D tool to a file format that you can *parse*. Then you can use the parsed information to get the data in some *format* (not file format) your program can use.

As an example, consider the *[wavefront obj](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file)* file format. A typical obj file looks something like this:

```
# ('#' is for comments, just ignore it)
# PURELY USELESS .obj file
v 0.123 0.234 0.345  # 'v' represents vertex
v 0.122 1.034 3.042
vt 0.500 1           # 'vt' represents texture/uv
vt 0.042 0.889
vn 0.707 0.000 0.707 # 'vn' stands for normal
vn 0.367 0.367 0.000
f 6/4/1 3/5/3 7/6/5  # 'f' stands for face
# there are other things too, like material ('usemtl') etc
```

Considering you want to use an object represented as the above file in your project, you will have to parse the file to get information into, say arrays. One array each for vertices, normals, texture/uv's and faces (there might be more, and you might need less).

So, there are a few steps:

1. Create an object using some tool, you will prefer Blender since it is FOSS.
2. Export it to some format you can parse, like Obj or Collada.
3. Parse the *exported* file to the manner you wish to use (most probably like in some Android OpenGL example you are following)
4. Get this data into buffers and render it.

---

If I were you, I would start the way they do in the examples. Start with a cube or some other simple shape. IIRC a cube is the default shape in blender, so exporting is as simple as following some basic blender tutorial. You can then grow from there.

Also, creating objects and applying images (*textures*) to them is not exactly a skill you can pick up while writing *for loops*, and not as quick as well, so you might want to get help from some designer/3D-artist or free online stuff etc.

Comment: can u help us... suggest some name........

Comment: Name for what? 3D Software?

Comment: i need the proper 3D software for android openGLES and roadmap for AR. how can i integrate 3D object file into android openGLES? i need proper tutorial or training...